# Why am I getting a protocol error creating a laravel project in Vagrant Homestead?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, homestead

I keep getting a protocol error when I try to use "laravel new Laravel" inside of the homestead ~/Code directory. If I use the command in the home directory it creates the project without any issues, so I tried moving the created project from the home directory and into the ~/Code directory and still got a protocol error trying to move it. Has anyone run into this issue? I have been googling for about two hours now and haven't found any useful information :/

I installed Laravel on the box using the installer method (composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1")

Thanks to whoever helps, I really appreciate it this is so frustrating.

- Trevor Kavanaugh

Comment: I can't create any files inside of the ~/Code directory even using sudo.. I am assuming it is a shared folder issue but I honestly have no clue how to fix this. Still googling though!

Answer (score 0):

Found it out lol, I did not have read/write permissions on the shared host folder *facepalm*